# How to represent recurring fixed-term contracts

Tags: resume, contracting

For the last 3 years, I have taught in an engineering school, usually between September and March. It is legally sealed with a fixed-term contract (as a regular employee contract, not as freelancer).

It represents 5 contracts, over 2 to 7 months, ranging from 10 to 40 hours with lessons lasting from 1 to 4 hours.

I do it part-time. I have had full-time jobs over this period.

On my resumé I have wrote a line per contract (as "Occasional Haskell Teacher"), should I still represent it like that? (My worries come from the fact that my other main jobs are less visible compared to my teaching jobs).

Comment: I would make it one line in my CV, you can discuss the details afterwards...

Comment: Just asking, are two full-time jobs (as per the contracts) at the same time is allowed in your locale? As you mentioned, you do this part time, but does the contract mentions as such (you said regular employee)?

Comment: Maybe just "Contract Haskell Teacher"  there's no need to say "occasional" as it is obvious/implied

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is a bit complicated (for the record I live and work in France). Technically, these are considered as two full time jobs, it is allowed, but I have some limitations (like the number of consecutive hours I can work, or the number of hours a day/week I can work, and so on). The other thing I have to consider is to not be prohibited by my contract (which was the case in my first company, unless I ask my employer).

Comment: @LaurentS. and would you put the date when you begin doing it?

Comment: @GlinesMome > Sure! It is quite common to see it done like that. I've had several colleagues who also happened to be teaching evening classes and they all represented it that way on their LinkedIn profile/CV.

Comment: I have a section on my resume that just says 
Teaching and Tutoring   /  Nov 2000 - Present   /  Various positions including XXX, XXX, XXX

Comment: "Occasional" is not a good word to use, it sounds unprofessional and suggests infrequent and brief employment which seems to be seriously understating the work you've done. Something more professional like freelance, part-time, or contract is more suited to a CV, but no qualifier is actually required.

Answer (score 2):

You are a Haskell Teacher.

Some countries would consider the practice put upon you (on and off employment) as labor exploitation (would be different in the freelancing case). Basically the employers business risks are rolled off upon you, which is in the employment and labor law not acceptable by most countries.

A court of law could determine you are actually a permanent employee since 3 years. Such rulings have happened in the past in equal cases (mostly Europe).

Comment: (There are also countries, e.g. Germany, where putting such a teaching job down as freelancing may come at a high risk of being put down as social insurance fraud [Scheinselbständigkeit], making "project" employment contracts a legally safer option)